# Sync keys from a dictionary to multiple values in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

i have a dict of list in following format,

```
mydict = 

{ a: [1, 2],
  b: [2, 2],
  c: [1, 0],
  d: [1, 1]
}
```

and another list with just two elements,

```
mylist =
    [x, y]
```

I read the values from `mydict` like this

```
for key, values in mydict.items():
    print key, values
```

this prints,

```
  a [1, 2]
  b [2, 2]
  c [1, 0]
  d [1, 1]
```

but i want the following output,

```
x : [1, 2, 1, 1]
y : [2, 2, 0, 1]
```

which means, the first column of `mydict` and first value of `mylist` makes a dictionary.

so i modified loop like this,

```
for key, values in mydict.items():
    newdict = {mylist[0]: mydict[0],
               mylist[1]: mydict[1] 
              }
```

which gives me the desired output,

```
x : [1, 2, 1, 1]
y : [2, 2, 0, 1]
```

but the problem is if the length of `mylist` and `mydict` increases then it won't work, and I need to manually add a new line,

```
mylist[2]: mydict[2]
```

How can I make sure that keys are assigned automatically without add a new line, everytime new value in `mylist` is added?

PS: lenth of list value in `mydict` will always be equal to length of `mylist`.

**Edit:**

my output should also preserve value of keys from `mydict`,

```
x : [1, 2, 1, 1]
y : [2, 2, 0, 1]
keys: a, b, c, d
```

thank you

**EDIT:**

```
        0        1
0       a        [1,2],
1       b        [2,2],
2       c        [1,0],   
3       d        [1,1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working with big data, you can use `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd

mydict = { 'a': [1, 2],
  'b': [2, 2],
  'c': [1, 0],
  'd': [1, 1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(mydict)

    0   1
a   1   2
b   2   2
c   1   0
d   1   1
```

Then you can get, e.g.

```
>>> df.columns = ['x', 'y'] # where ['x', 'y'] is your obj my_list
>>> df.to_dict('list')

{'x': [1, 2, 1, 1], 'y': [2, 2, 0, 1]}
```

---

To keep the keys

```
>>> d = df.to_dict('list')
>>> d.update({'keys':df.index.tolist()})
```

Comment: i dont know what is bigdata and i am not using it

Comment: I meant if your lists and dicts are very very big :)

Comment: i like you approach more since i have 1000s of rows now and only now realized this is better. I tried your answer but its not working. can you check updated question please? i added the output of `df = pd.DataFrame(mydict.items())`

Comment: @MaverickD Use `pd.DataFrame(mydict)` and not `pd.DataFrame(mydict.items())` :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use **`zip`** <sup>2</sup>

```
dict(zip(['x', 'y'], zip(*dct.values())))

# Result
{'x': (1, 2, 1, 1), 'y': (2, 2, 0, 1)}
```

This uses the **`zip`** transpose:

```
>>> list(zip(*dct.values()))
[(1, 2, 1, 1), (2, 2, 0, 1)]
```

If you want to keep your keys:

```
dict(zip(['key', 'x', 'y'], zip(*[(i, *j) for i, j in dct.items()])))

# Result
{'key': ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), 'x': (1, 2, 1, 1), 'y': (2, 2, 0, 1)}
```

Comment: can you please explain what did you do there? i didn't check it, but i also want to preserve and print value of `keys` in `mydict` i.e. `a`,`b`,`c`

Comment: What do you mean preserve and print value of keys?

Comment: i mean that inside the for loop i should be able to print 
`{'x': (1, 2, 1, 1), 'y': (2, 2, 0, 1)}` and `keys: a, b, c, d`

Comment: You need to update your question to clarify exactly what you want your output to be.

Comment: if i use yours method i will lose keys also is `*dct.values` means `mydict`?

Comment: i modified quiestion